# Area of a Rindler horizon

Tags: general-relativity

Is there someone who can show me how to calculate the area of a Rindler horizon and its distance from the observer (whose acceleration causes the horizon to be created) as a function of the magnitude of that acceleration?

Comment: The horizon is an infinite plane so its area is infinite ...

Comment: Can you give us some idea of what you already know about this. For example do you know the Rindler metric?

Comment: My understanding ohat the horizon represented a patch of the accelerating observer's "sky"  and that no beam of light could ever reach him from behind that patch

Comment: I know that Rindler coordinates are used to describe the physics here but I do not know how to relate the curves on a Rindler "chart" to the observations of a uniformly accelerating observer. My general understanding was that the horizon represented a patch of the accelerating observer's "sky" and that behind that patch no beam of light could ever reach him. My mistaken understanding was that the size of that patch depended on the magnitude of his acceleration- that for very small accelerations, the patch shrank, and for large accelerations, it grew. Is this in fact a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rindler metric is given by:

$$\mathrm  ds^2 = -\left(1 + \frac{a\,x}{c^2} \right)^2 c^2\mathrm  dt^2 +\mathrm  dx^2 +\mathrm  dy^2 + \mathrm  dz^2  $$

Light rays follow paths that make $\mathrm  ds^2=0$, so the velocity of light turns out to be: $$ v_c=c(1+\frac{ax}{c^2}) $$

This is zero when light is at: $$x=-\frac{c^2}{a} \tag{1}$$

In three dimensions, the above equation represents a plane at that position w.r.t the observer.

A plane has infinite area, so the area of the Rindler horizon is independent of $a$. $a$ only decides its position.